# Scala replace one text for another text with special chars included

Tags: scala

i need a function to replace one text per another one, currently this is the code i am using, but it's not really working, or at least instead of replacing, removing the text and leave it empty, this is the code:

Thanks for your time, appreciated

```
def replaceIcons(message: String) = {
    message.replaceAll("[|TInterfaceiconsInv_Misc_Tournaments_banner_Human.png:13,8:14:0,9:-2,8|t]:", "[https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/511683443231424532.png?v=1]:")
  }
```

This is the message i want to replace [i.postimg.cc/zDHwfXHX/ser.png](https://i.postimg.cc/zDHwfXHX/ser.png)

The expected output is this one: [i.postimg.cc/k4mCt5X3/serr.png](https://i.postimg.cc/k4mCt5X3/serr.png)

Example message to replace:

[global] [Zerobalas]: [|TInterfaceiconsInv_Misc_Tournaments_banner_Human.png:13,8:14:0,9:-2,8|t]: asd

Example output expected:

[global] [Zerobalas]: [https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/511683443231424532.png?v=1]: asd

Comment: Can you post what is the message you want to replace and what is the expected output

Comment: Sure, this is the message i want to replace https://i.postimg.cc/zDHwfXHX/ser.png,
the expected output is this one: https://i.postimg.cc/k4mCt5X3/serr.png

Comment: Only those strings? nothing else?

Comment: add the example and expected output as text

Comment: try `message.replace(...`

Comment: yeah like that replaceAll should work, or replace

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regular expression. If you don't need that, use `replace` (which also replaces *all* occurances, but uses exact substring match, not regular expressions).

Comment: @Thilo But, i have to Escape something or i just put it without doing any Escape?

Comment: No, no need to escape anything (beyond the usual rules for String literals in Java source code). Nothing in your example.

Comment: @Thilo I tried it, but doesn't work with replace, i used this code:

https://pastebin.com/K3xupVYZ

Comment: And you are sure the `message` contains *exactly* that replacement String (character for character)?

Comment: What do you mean with "that replacement String (character for character)"?
Edit: Well, the string "message" contains also other characters inside, the replacement is just for a part of message, the original message contains:

[global] [Zerobalas]: [|TInterfaceiconsInv_Misc_Tournaments_banner_Human.png:13,8:14:0,9:-2,8|t]: blablabla

And it should be:

[global] [Zerobalas]: [https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/511683443231424532.png?v=1]: asd

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def replaceIcons(message: String) = {
    message.replace("[|TInterfaceiconsInv_Misc_Tournaments_banner_Human.png:13,8:14:0,9:-2,8|t]:", "[https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/511683443231424532.png?v=1]:")
  }

  println(replaceIcons("[global] [Zerobalas]: [|TInterfaceiconsInv_Misc_Tournaments_banner_Human.png:13,8:14:0,9:-2,8|t]: asd"))
```